# How can set a property using the same name without changing existing value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, dynamicobject

Using JavaScript, how can I set property of an object that already has property with the same name? For example, what i want to output is:

```
var obj = {
    name: "foo"
};

obj[name] = "baz";
```

Normal output is:

`console.log(obj) => {name:baz}`.

I want to output:

`console.log(obj) => {name:foo,name:baz}`.

I know that is not the best practice, but is that possible?

Comment: it is impossible to have two keys that are the same in an object. Maybe you should think about using an array if you need multiple values.

Comment: I'm not sure what your reasoning is, but ask yourself: _"what would `obj.name` point to if you could have multiple of the same keys?"_ If you want to store multiple names, either use `const names = [...]` or `obj = { names: [] }`

Comment: thanks for response. I try to dynamic create obj by months. its 13 piece. One mouth must be dublicate in object. why i am using this method. any advice for that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can read about [core js concepts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) and also about basic data types in programming, like Maps and Arrays.

I can try to guess that your task is to store some similar data structures in array:

```
var list = [{name:'foo'},{name:'baz'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply can't do that. The latest value of the property will always override the previous one.

Even merging objects with same property names won't help you - shallow merge, or deep merge.

However, there are a few very weird cases with some JavaScript frameworks where this might happen - in Vue.js, for instance. But that misses the point since we're considering only plain Javascript.